# Why my Facebook Profile can't be visible from outside (while logged-out)?

Tags: facebook, profile, privacy, invisible

While i'm logged out, my Facebook Profile **can not** be seen then.
I just wanna let others see me when i give them my link.
All others Facebook Profiles can be viewed without login.
I mean, for example you can see yourself:

```
https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

For my profile, it is showing like:

> This content is currently unavailable!
>   The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.

What privacy tweak should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your [Privacy Settings page](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy), then Apps and Websites, then Public Search.
There you can enable Public Search.

Comment: I am checking for this and only found apps option. Where it is saying that "On Facebook, your name, profile picture, cover photo, gender, networks, username, and user id are always publicly available ..." but still not showing profile :(

Comment: Try Privacy -> Who can look me up? -> Do you want other search engines to link to your timeline?

Set to "Yes".